# Making a list of connected clients and broadcasting a message to them in a simple Java web chat

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server, lan

I'm trying to make a simple Java web chat.So far i have succeeded in the basic functionality but the problem remains of Server sending a message to clients and clients receiving other client messages.I thought of making an arraylist containing clients so that i could broadcast messages to all of them at once or the one that i choose yet that doesn't work.Am i looking at this the wrong way and should i rewrite the Server code or even the client code?

Crux of the Server code.

```
public class Server{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<User> useragents = new ArrayList<>();
    User useragent=new User();
    ServerThread t;
    String usernamestring;
    static int sameusernamecount;
    static int allconnectedusercount;

   static class User{
        Socket clientSocket;
        PrintWriter out;
        BufferedReader in;
        String msgin=" ";
        String msgout="";


    }



public void StartServer(int port){

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket client;

        System.out.println("Server launched.");
        System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");



            while(true){

                System.out.println(useragent+"agent");
                useragent.clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                useragents.add(useragent);
                ServerThread t = new ServerThread();
                t.start();






            }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }





}
class ServerThread extends Thread{
    void CloseSockets(){
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
            useragent.clientSocket.close();
            useragent.in.close();
            useragent.out.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }




public void run(){

    try{
        useragent.out = new PrintWriter(useragent.clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        useragent.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(useragent.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        usernamestring=useragent.in.readLine();
        System.out.println("New User has connected:"+usernamestring);
        names.add(usernamestring);





    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);



        while(useragent.msgin!=null) {



            useragent.msgin = useragent.in.readLine();
            String[] split=useragent.msgin.split(":");
            String Username=split[0];
            String Message=split[1];
            if(ContainsString(Username)==true){
                Username+=1;

            }
            System.out.println(Username+":"+Message);
            useragent.msgout=Username+":"+Message;

            if(Message.equals("/break")){
                break;
            }
            if(Message.equals("/listusers")){
                System.out.println("Users Connected:"+names);
            }
            System.out.println(names);

            for(int i=0;i<useragents.size();i++){
                useragents.get(i).out.println(useragent.msgout);
             
            }}
```

Crux of the client code

```
 private void SendMessage(){
        String msgout=" ";
        String msgin=" ";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            out.println(username);
            while (msgout != null){
                try {
                    msgout =scan.nextLine();
                    out.println(username + ":" + msgout);


                    if (msgout.equals("/break")) {
                        out.println(username+" has disconnected");
                        break;
                    }

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                }
            }

        try {
            clientSocket.close();
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

    }
    private void ReceiveMessage(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while(true) {
                        String msgfromgroupchat;
                        msgfromgroupchat = in.readLine();
                        System.out.println(msgfromgroupchat);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                }
            }
        }).start();{

        }
    }
```